# fb_ref parameter missing from timeline links

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ref

our software relies on the ref parameter passed to likes and custom actions to track attribution. Since this morning the fb_ref parameter has stopped appearing on like links on the timeline and is appearing embedded in a different parameter in custom action links on the timeline. Examples below...

This is a timeline link for a Like made 18 hours ago. It has the fb_ref parameter:

http://prod.demo.smartsaasp.techlightenment.com/ecommerce/product/?id=1407109375&fb_ref=1002100600__I8RH9f_yxWiH4DJKIMuhm_1407109375&fb_source=timeline

This is a timeline link for a Like made today. It is missing an fb_ref parameter. Also note that fb_source=aggregation, even though the link is appearing in the same style as the previous example (fb_source=timeline):

http://prod.demo.smartsaasp.techlightenment.com/ecommerce/product/?id=184537892X&fb_action_ids=10151115280129669&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=288381481237582

This is a link from the recent activity panel in the timeline for a Like made today. It is missing an fb_ref parameter:

prod.demo.smartsaasp.techlightenment.com/ecommerce/product/?id=184537892X&fb_action_ids=10151115280129669&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map=%7B%2210151115280129669%22%3A10151068797314544%7D&action_type_map=%7B%2210151115280129669%22%3A%22og.likes%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D

Finally, this is a link from the recent activity panel in the timeline for custom edge (view) made today. It actually has our trackcode embedded within the action_object_map parameter, but does not contain an fb_ref parameter.

prod.demo.smartsaasp.techlightenment.com/ecommerce/product/?id=184537892X&fb_action_ids=10151115279759669&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map=%7B%2210151115279759669%22%3A10151068797314544%7D&action_type_map=%7B%2210151115279759669%22%3A%22scrm-ecommerce-prd%3Aview%22%7D&action_ref_map=%7B%2210151115279759669%22%3A%221002F00400_*E6a0*_zsqF3j4e3vInVUiN184537892X%22%7D

I assure you that the ref parameter is being correctly sent when we do likes and custom edges.

Can anyone help?